# Why a certain keys on my keyboard not working in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

So recently I was configuring some key bindings and snippets in VS Code and now the letter K is not showing up in the editor.
When I press the key K, I get the message at the bottom of my screen saying **"K was pressed wait for a second cord**.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: So it turned out I solved the problem. The issue was that I had tried to create a custom keyboard shortcut using the letter k. When I removed this shortcut the keyboard worked fine.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be because you have created some keyboard shortcuts that are conflicting
with certain keys on the keyboard.
Go through all your keyboard shortcuts and remove the ones that are causing this
conflict.

It could also, be causes by some extensions. To fix this try restarting your pc
and restarting vs code as well as removing the potentially buggy extensions.